# Dumping and importing with backslash

Tags: mysql, backup, import

**Background**

I have a MySQL database, from which I run `mysqldump` for backups.

In this database, I have some fields that will contain some backslashes, and when dumping this, it will contain something like

```
INSERT INTO table1 (col1, col2) VALUES (1, '\frac{1}{2}');
```

(For reference, this is [TeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeX), used in this case for typesetting mathematics.)

**Problem**

Now, when I import this backup with

```
mysql -u username -p database_name < file.sql
```

the backslash in the `col2` value disappears. Likely, instead of inserting it, it's being used to escape the following character.

**Question**

Is there a way to insert this while maintaining the backslash?

My idea so far is to make a script that plows through the file and replaces every occurrence of `\` with `\\`. Is this reliable?

I would assume that someone already thought of this problem and maybe created some way of dealing with it.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you use mysqldump to export your data it will take care of this for you. For example:

```
mysql> select * from table1;
+------+-------------+
| id   | mystr       |
+------+-------------+
|    1 | \frac{1}{2} |
+------+-------------+

mysqldump -uroot -p database1 table1 > table1.sql

cat table1.sql | grep VALUES
INSERT INTO `table1` VALUES (1,'\\frac{1}{2}');
```

notice the escaped backslash? and:

```
mysql -uroot -p database1 < table1.sql

mysql -uroot -p database1 -e "select * from table1"
Enter password: 
+------+-------------+
| id   | mystr       |
+------+-------------+
|    1 | \frac{1}{2} |
+------+-------------+
```

Comment: Oh, that's odd. My dumps aren't getting the doubled backslash. Is there some setting for that?

Comment: What you see is what you get. Default mysqldump for MySQL version 5.7.

Answer (score 0):

In what context did you run the `INSERT`?  Most client languages have a way of "escaping what needs to be escaped for MySQL".  Such a function would take care of doubling up the backslash and dealing with quotes.

Comment: The `INSERT` was run by connecting to the database and running commands from the dumped file.

Comment: Are you saying that the output from mysql dump had a single backslash in that context?